# How many posts does the loop return?

Tags: posts, loop

I am creating a child theme archive template. I don't know how many posts will be displayed, which is fine except that i want to have a dividing line  after each post except the last one.

I am using the usual loop,  have added a `$loopcount` variable, and then an include to create the formatting/display and add the `<div class="divider"></div>`:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$loopCount++;
include(locate_template('template-parts/content-newsandevents.php'));
endwhile;
```

I have looked in the codex but I can't find a way to know how many posts the loop is going to do in advance. (I could use jQ to do this, but it would be neater to do it with php I think)

Comment: have you considered using `get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'newsandevents' );`?

Comment: Yes - I can't use get_template_part because I need to send a variable into the include - hence the use of `include(locate_template('template-parts/content-newsandevents.php'));`

Comment: @TomJNowell Not everybody uses the `get_template_part`. Some people use the simplest themes in the old manner.

Comment: have you tried using the `:last` css selector instead?

Comment: yes, with a display:none - that would work. But i'd prefer not to create it ideally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reversing the logic, put the dividing line before the post but only do it after the first post.

To answer your question though, you can get the loop count with the following:

```
global $wp_query;
$count = count( $wp_query->posts );
// or
$count = $wp_query->post_count;
```

Comment: thanks for this Welcher. I tried both methods, and in the end went for the logic change - just neater that way.

Answer (score 1):

By default it is 10.

You can change it from "Settings -> Reading" and then "Blog pages show at most"

URL - http://www.yoursite.com/wp-admin/options-reading.php

Comment: Yes thanks - I know that - but what if there are only 7 - there must be a way I can know  how many the loop is going to do.